# How fast is a Quickling courier?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, homebrew

I would like to implement a "postal service" in my 5e campaign, wherein the fastest deliveries are carried out by Quicklings. Their base speed is 120 ft, but that doesn't seem a good way to measure how fast they would be able to traverse, say, 1500 mi of the Sword Coast. How would one go about calculating how many days it would take a Quickling to traverse such a distance? A reasonable homebrew solution is acceptable, but it should hew as closely to the rules as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Refer to the DMG's special travel pace rules

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* includes [Special Travel Pace](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#SpecialTravelPace) rules for figuring out how quickly creatures can travel when they have an unusual method of getting around:

> A character bestride a phantom steed, soaring through the air on a carpet of flying, or riding a sailboat or a steam-powered gnomish contraption doesn’t travel at a normal rate, since the magic, engine, or wind doesn’t tire the way a creature does and the air doesn’t contain the types of obstructions found on land.

This section explains that the normal rules for travel in the *PHB* assume that, regardless of their speed in combat, in overland travel the differences between characters and creatures all average out and they move at roughly the same pace. However, when characters have access to an unusual method of transportation, you can use alternative rules to determine how quickly they go.

As written, none of this applies to the quickling, because they simply have a very high natural speed and are not flying, or powered by magic, or anything like that. However, these rules are the only alternative the game offers to the normal rate of travel described in the *PHB*, so if you rule that quicklings should count as having a special travel pace, this is what we have to work with.

According to these rules, a quickling with a base speed of 120ft can go:

- 1200 feet in a minute (800 at slow pace, 1600 fast)
- 12 miles in an hour (8 at slow pace, 16 fast)
- 96 miles in an 8-hour travelling day (64 at slow pace, 128 fast)

Using these rules, a quickling travelling at fast pace for 8 hours a day would cover 1500 miles in just under 12 days. (Note that this is very close, but not identical, to simply multiplying the standard rates of travel described in the *PHB* by 4, which is congruent with the assumption of a 30ft standard movement speed in those rules, as used in [Thomas Markov's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/183822/28402).)

The quickling can also attempt a [forced march](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/adventuring#TravelPace), as per the rules from the *PHB*:

> For each additional hour of travel beyond 8 hours, the characters cover the distance shown in the Hour column for their pace, and each character must make a Constitution saving throw at the end of the hour. The DC is 10 + 1 for each hour past 8 hours. On a failed saving throw, a character suffers one level of exhaustion.

With a +1 constitution save modifier, they will on average be able to travel for an extra two hours before one level of exhaustion sets in, from which they recover while they rest; a quickling making such haste would average 160 miles per day at a fast pace, reducing a 1500-mile journey to about 9 and a half days.

Just for the sake of completeness, a quickling that was immune to exhaustion and did not need to sleep could max out their speed at 384 miles over 24 hours, and cover a 1500-mile distance in almost 4 days. Unfortunately, despite their description as "never truly at rest", nothing in the quickling's statistics actually prevent it from needing to sleep or becoming exhausted.

### How about the Quickling Express?

As [Alan Régis' answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/183852/28402) points out, real-world express postal services with mounted riders didn't rely on a single horse for the entire journey; the postal service operated a network of stations with freshly rested horses ready to use, so the courier could ride their horses hard from station to station and switch to a new horse whenever they needed one.

If you apply the same principle to a quickling postal network, and allow that there is a network of rest stations for quicklings such that one courier can do their full day's travel and then pass on their deliveries to another quickling courier, a Quickling Express delivery could be moving at very nearly 24 hours per day and travelling nearly 384 miles per day (quicklings have darkvision, so there's no reason they can't travel at night). This requires such a rest station roughly every 160 miles along the journey's route, which doesn't seem an unreasonable prospect for an organised postal service.

Taking it a step even further, the *PHB*'s normal travel rules do allow that *mounted* characters can ride their mounts at a gallop for about an hour, covering even greater ground:

> For short spans of time (up to an hour), many animals move much faster than humanoids. A mounted character can ride at a gallop for about an hour, covering twice the usual distance for a fast pace.

Quicklings are not mounted nor mounts, but if you decided to apply this rule to them as well, a quickling at a gallop could cover 32 miles in one hour, and if a sufficiently dense network of Quickling Express stations existed that the delivery could be handed off to a fresh quickling every hour, the delivery could go at nearly 768 miles per day, reducing that 1500-mile journey to just under 2 days. Of course, that does depend on the transport network having a Quickling Express station every 32 miles and a very large number of cooperative quicklings, the former which may be infeasible and the latter of which seems very unlikely.

Comment: Also: These courier runners definitely would have expertise in forced marches con saves. I know that's not directly possible RAW, but it just makes sense (and RAW/expertise is meant for PCs so it works)

Comment: @Hobbamok just giving them proficiency in con saves at all would bump that up to +3 and put them up to 12 hours/192 miles per day on average.

Comment: Don't usually like to move accepted answers, but I think I didn't give it enough time-- I think your answer is more in the spirit of what I was looking for. But wow, both you and @Thomas Markov provided two outstanding answers that I just wasn't expecting with this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

#### Use the usual travel pace rules, times 4.

The exploration chapter of the *Player’s Handbook* contains rules for players to measure daily travel pace:

> While traveling, a group of adventurers can move at a normal, fast, or slow pace, as shown on the Travel Pace table. The table states how far the party can move in a period of time and whether the pace has any effect. A fast pace makes characters less perceptive, while a slow pace makes it possible to sneak around and to search an area more carefully (see the “Activity While Traveling” section later in this chapter for more information).

PCs *usually* have a speed of 30 feet, and the numbers on that table are written with that assumption. Since your quickling courier has a base speed of 120, which is four times 30, just use the base measurements in the travel pace table multiplied by a factor of four.

A PC with a speed of 30 feet can travel 24 miles a day at a normal pace, so a quickling should be able to travel 96 miles per day at the normal pace. At a fast pace, a quickling can cover 120 miles per day, so should be able to cover your 1500 mile target in 12.5 days.

Comment: Then, the PC traveling time is factoring in that they sprint faster than they cover miles.  OTOH, there are no rules specifying whether a quickling's speed is greater when sprinting, or the same as when distance running.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, and I actually already came up with it-- the issue is that it just doesn't seem to take into account the Quickling's special ability. 120 ft speed really isn't that fast honestly, so I was thinking there might be some other information that coule be used. :)

Comment: @Mary A creature’s base speed is its “walking” speed, a quickling’s when sprinting (using the Dash action) is 240.

Comment: "Walking" in a fight is not the same as walking all day.

Comment: @Mary if we take the default speed of 30 feet per round (=6s) and calculate how far one would get if traveling at this speed for 8 hours, we get 30*10*60*8=144000ft, or roughly 27 miles. Thus, the walking speed outside of combat is just barely below the walking speed in combat, and it's very much possible that the reduction to 24 miles is merely for the purpose of easier calculation, as 24 can easily be divided by 2, 3, 4, 6, 8 and 12, whereas 27 is only divisible by 3 and 9. Therefore, I do believe that multiplying the Quicklings out-of-combat walking speed by 4 is completely valid.

Answer (score 4):

### You can use some real life equivalents

A good one would be the [mongolian horseman messengers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yam_(route)#:%7E:text=%C3%96gedei%20Khan%20gave%20special%20attention,process%20of%20information%20and%20intelligence.). They had a superior network of outposts with rested horses always ready, so the messenger could easily cover up to 190 miles per day.

Do you want your postal service to be faster than normal mundane speeds? A Quickling have twice the speed of a regular horse, and although some can argue that he could get tired faster, for example, there's no reason not to use the same mongolian system in a postal service (a bunch of outposts with rested quicklings ready to resume the delivery). This makes it possible to have a non stop 24h service, bypassing the standard barrier of how long a single creature can travel per day).

Based on that, i would say that a speed of 300-380 miles per day would be pretty impressive while still ""realistic"" (1500 miles in roughly 4 days).

Comment: Yep, I'm now building a "Quickling Express" service in my game. Amazing. <3

Answer (score 2):

## As fast as you want.

Especially with the Quickling, this might be a good point to take a little break from mechanics and read their lore instead:

> Quicklings rocket through haunting, twisted forests where the Unseelie fey hold sway, both in the Feywild and in the world. Racing faster than the eye can track, each appears as little more than a blurry wavering in the air.

Does that sound like something going 60km/h? Because that's what 120ft + dash + bouns action dash is. And while 60km/h is fast, I don't think anyone would describe a cheetah (which moves twice as fast in real life) as "little more than a blurry wavering in the air"

The Quickling's base speed is more likely chosen as a mechanical limitation so their movement fits on a battlemap, or maybe as symbolizing their ability to weave around in battle.

But every word of their lore describes them as *blindingly fast*, not just a few times quicker than a human. As a result, if you want to use them to set up a courier service, I'd play on their lore more than their mechanics. Let them traverse the whole Sword Coast in a day. Why not?

I've used Quicklings in a campaign before, and the players first encountered them when they found a shrine in the forest that had fresh flowers that only grew on the other side of the kingdom. They learned that Quicklings can, and do, cross across the whole kingdom in an hour, just to deliver flowers. It didn't seem crazy, or overpowered, and lent a more mystical feel to these little Fey.

In a world of Sending and Teleport, being able to move messages and packages overland at a few hundred miles per hour isn't overpowered or unbelievable, and if you're going to use the fastest creatures in the game to do it, I'd just go all out.

Comment: Good perspective. If they have a way to move to/from Feywild, then distances do not matter either, as both time and distance flow differently there. They could just dash to a nearby fey crossing, travel quickly to another one there, and move back out in an entirely different place on the world map within hours.